# How to calculate average time for each month and plot line clustered column chart in Power Bi

Tags: time

I have data of 12 months containing calls and time for each calls.
I want to plot a line clustered column chart showing average duration for each month and calls handled each month.

I tried average formula but it does not give the required results.